# How to highlight the title in r markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

i tried to highlight the subtitle in r markdown, but the latex code cannot be run successfully.

```
---
title: "k"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-03-06"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{soul}
---

## \hl{Unadjusted}
```

The result is :
[image]

How to highlight `Unadjusted`? I tried many methods and was still unsuccessful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extra_dependencies:

```
---
title: "k"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: "soul"  
date: "2023-03-06"
---

## \hl{Unadjusted}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the rmarkdown with instant result?

Answer (score 1):

Using `subtitle` in YAML header.

```
---
title: "k"
subtitle: \hl{Unadjusted}
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-03-06"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{soul}
---
```

[image]